# Как присвоить результат выполнения двух функций python в одну переменную и одну строку

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, переменные

У меня есть две функции:

```
def replacer(text):
    return text.replace('*', '')

def replacer_(text):
    return text.replace('!', '')
```

И текст который должен передаваться каждой из функций выше:

```
text = '*ello worl**!'
```

Мне необходимо после выполнения этих двух функций получить результат:

```
text = 'ello worl'
```

Я хочу написать код в одну строку, который мог бы присвоить и дать возможность использовать результат одной функции другой, чтобы не пришлось писать так и код был в одну строку (примеры ниже отображают нежелательный для меня код, для получения общего результата):

```
# первый плохой пример
result1 = replacer(text)
result = replacer_(result1)

# второй плохой пример
result1 = replacer(text); result = replacer_(result1)
```

Почему эти примеры являются для меня плохими и почему они нежелательны с моей стороны:

1. Мои названия функций гораздо больше, чем приведены на примерах
2. Название моей переменной с текстом гораздо больше, чем приведена на примере
3. Код который был приведен выше, был добавлен в качестве примеров, чтобы решить мою другую текущую проблему, которая с этим связана (поэтому здесь всё на примерах)
4. Из-за подозрения что это можно сделать более лучше, чем делать идентичные действия одного к другому

Также не хотелось бы видеть (из-за причин указанных выше):

```
result = replacer(replacer_(text))
```

Comment: "Код который был приведен выше, был добавлен в качестве примеров, чтобы решить мою другую текущую проблему" - лучше опишите суть того, что вам нужно сделать на самом деле. "Проблема", описанная в вопросе решается __одним__ вызовом "str.translate" для удаления __всех__ нежелательных символов

Comment: @MaxU есть значения в строке, которые я хотел бы изменить на какие-либо другие значения

Comment: Значения односимвольные?

Comment: @MaxU нет, но я точно знаю какие значения на что нужно изменить, нужен просто пример изменения значений в строке, наподобие ключа и значение на которое будет изменено прошлое значение, чтобы не приходилось множество раз писать `text.replace('что', 'на что')` и код желательно должен быть в одну строку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во внешней библиотеке [toolz](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) есть несколько подходящих функций, в частности

> [compose](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.functoolz.compose)(f, g, h, ...)(x) = f(g(h(...(x))))
> [compose_left](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.functoolz.compose_left)(f, g, h, ...)(x) = ...(h(g(f(x))))
> [pipe](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.functoolz.pipe)(x, f, g, h, ...) = ...(h(g(f(x))))

```py
from toolz import pipe

result = pipe('*ello worl**!', replacer, replacer_)
```

Более содержательный пример

```
from toolz import compose_left

replacers = replacer, replacer_
replace_all = compose_left(*replacers)
result = replace_all('*ello worl**!')
```

Comment: открыл для себя `toolz.pipe` - спасибо! (-:

Comment: @extrn как использовать вместе с асинхронными функциями?

Comment: @MaximChyorny пожалуй, никак. В том смысле, что дополнительного выигрыша в производительности не получится, ведь функции применяются последовательно в строгом порядке.

Comment: @extrn ну окей, пускай даже дополнительного выигрыша в производительности не будет, но как их в `pipe` запихнуть, иначе `pipe` для меня теряет смысл, так как мои функции асинхронные.

Comment: @MaximChyorny ну да, в этом случае потребуется написать собственную асинхронную версию `pipe`. Возьмите [исходник](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/toolz/functoolz.html#pipe) функции, благо он элементарный, и добавьте `async`/`await`

Answer (score 4):

Можно создать простую функцию, принимающую на вход исходную строку и словарь со всеми заменами, которая будет в цикле делать замены:

```
# словарь замен: ключ - что меняем, значение - на что заменяем
mapping = {
  "hi": "привет",
  "all": "всем",
  "how are you doing": "как дела"
}


def repl(s, map_):
    res = s
    # делаем в цикле все замены согласно словарю замен
    for k, v in map_.items():
        res = res.replace(k, v)
    return res
```

Пример использования:

```
In [301]: repl("hi all! how are you doing?", mapping)
Out[301]: 'привет всем! как дела?'
```

Comment: ок, могли бы добавить информации в код, на какой строке что и где выполняется

Comment: @MaximChyorny, добавил комментарии в код

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать ещё вот так: просто записать все нужные функции в список и по очереди их применить. Хотя вариант MaxU с маппингом лучше/правильнее.

```
def replacer(text):
    return text.replace('*', '')

def replacer_(text):
    return text.replace('!', '')

text = '*ello worl**!'
replacers = [
    replacer, 
    replacer_
    ]
for r in replacers:
    text = r(text)
print(text)
```

Вывод:

```
ello worl
```

Answer (score 3):

По мотивам ответа @MaxU, но в один проход используя regexp.

```
import re

mapping = {
  "hi": "привет",
  "all": "всем",
  "how are you doing": "как дела"
}

def repl(s, map_):
    return re.sub("|".join(re.escape(k) for k in map_), lambda m: map_[m.group(0)], s)

print(repl("hi all! how are you doing?", mapping))
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
# Необходимый импорт
from functools import reduce

# Первая Ваша функция
def replacer(text):
    return text.replace('*', '')

# Вторая Ваша функция
def replacer_(text):
    return text.replace('!', '')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Исходный текст
    text = '*ello worl**!'

    # Применение всех функций к исходному тексту в одну строку
    result = reduce(lambda acc, func: func(acc), (replacer, replacer_), text)

    # Вывод результата
    print(result)
```

```py
result = reduce(lambda acc, func: func(acc), (replacer, replacer_), text)
#        ^ Свёртка
#               ^ Правило свёртки
#                                            ^ Множество объектов для свёртки
#                                                                   ^ Начальное значение
```

[functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).

Comment: Кстати, да, `reduce` как-раз про этот сценарий, забываю всё время про него.